# C++ Calculator, what method to calculate

Tags: c++

I'm trying to make a calculator.
It seems, that for it to make an addition you must declare variables x, y 
then add them `sum = x + y`.
My question is this, since you can say `cout << (2 + 6)`; and get a result of 8,
Why can't you do this:
Define variable `a`, with the correct data type and do
`cin >> a`; type in 2 + 6 then have
`cout<<(a)`; with a result of 8, since the variable was defined as 2 + 6, why 
doesn't that work?

Comment: The crucial point is _'with the correct data type'_. There's no standard data type available to do this.

Comment: C++ is a compiled language, and does not have dynamic expression evaluation

Comment: Of course you can do this. Provided that `a` is indeed of a correct data type. In this case `a` has to understand how to accept input from a `cin` via `std::istream` and how to interpret the provided user request (in your case - the input `2+6`). And then be able to output the result of the calculation into `cout`. All you need is to provide that "correct data type", which (most likely) would be a `class` you yourself design for this job

Comment: BTW, you might be looking for something similar to `eval()` which sadly c++ doesn't support

Answer (score 0):

As a simple pointer how such is solved in c++

```
int main() {
    int a = 0;
    int b = 0;
    std::string op;

    std::cin >> a >> op >> b;
    if(op == "+") {
        std::cout << a + b;
    }
    if(op == "-") {
        std::cout << a - b;
    }
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Lame. You're mixing textual representation `"+"`, where an enumeration should be used (at least in this case, if you're not using an associative container to map from identifier to its operation). We're not writing Javascript here, after all.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz Eh what? I said a **simple** pointer. You can of course provide a complicated, incomprehensible answer (for a beginner) describing a more sophisticated parser in your answer.

Comment: Such "simple" pointers produce programmers not understanding the benefits of proper static description of data in the long run. There's nothing complicated in typing your data properly; there's only laziness and lack of understanding that makes people do that. Point being, you shouldn't dumb down your answers just because the OP is a beginner.

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse the input.

this is quite complex and you also need to change prefix into reverse polish notation to take into account brackets etc.

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation

There is quite a few algorithms out there to change text and compute the answer